# QField SSL authentication and live project updates

Tags: qgis, postgresql, qfield, ssl, ssl-error

I'm currently having some issues with QField saving to a PostgreSQL database.
I believe that the issue lies with SSL being forced on the database end as i am able to have offline files work on QField but this isn't quite what I want.

What I need is for users on QField to be able to update the project and database entries in real time.I have already tried adding a file for pg_service.conf but am unsure if this is working as QField doesn't give me a prompt to enter any login credentials.

The simplest solution I see is to simply remove the SSL requirement but I've been told in no uncertain terms that this will not be happening from other people within my organisation.

If anyone requires more information just ask and ill do my best to provide some more detail.

Just wondering if anyone else has found a solution to this issue or has a workaround to allow to direct read write to the database from QField?

Comment: You don't have a question in your Question. Did you mean for this to be a bug report or enhancement request to the dev team?

Comment: the question is has anyone found a fix for getting QField to to read and write directly to the database whilst SSL is being forced or how i can get QField to submit credentials to the database for the login